# Subset sum of all vectors over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, combinations, finite-fields

Our vectors are in extended Galois field (GF). We specifically have GF($2^4$) with primitive polynomial $\alpha^4 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ where $\alpha$ is the primitive element in extended Galois field GF($2^4$). The elements of the GF($2^4$) generated by $\alpha$ as such $\{0, 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5,\alpha^6,\alpha^7,\alpha^8,\alpha^9,\alpha^{10},\alpha^{11},\alpha^{12},\alpha^{13},\alpha^{14}\}$.

The question is the following how to create vectors that all the sub-set sums results in vectors that have specific property. Before going to that property, we first take one of the normal group under addition $\{0, \alpha, 1, \alpha^4\}$, call the elements to be $C_1$ type, with corresponding cosets $\{\alpha^2, \alpha^5, \alpha^8, \alpha^{10}\}$ call the elements $C_2$ types, $\{\alpha^{13}, \alpha^6, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{11}\}$ call the elements $\{A, B, B, B\}$ type, and $\{\alpha^{14}, \alpha^3, \alpha^7, \alpha^{9}\}$ call the elements $\{B, A, A, A\}$ type. In addition let $0$ be $C'_1$ and $\alpha^2$ be $C'_2$. Therefore, property that need is that resultant vectors should have those rules

1. Any number of $C_1/C'_1$ (except for $C'_1$) and/or $C_2/C'_2$ (except for $C'_2$),
2. For each $C'_1$ there should be one $C'_2$ or vice versa
3. Else for each $C'_1$ there should be two $B$ types
4. Else for each $C'_2$ there should be two $A$ types
5. Else for each $A$ there should be one $B$ or vice versa.

   The matrix below satisfy this condition.
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & \alpha & 1 & \alpha^4 & 0 & \alpha & 1 & \alpha^4 \\
   0 & \alpha^6 & \alpha^{14} & \alpha^{11} & \alpha^6 & \alpha^8 & \alpha^{13} & \alpha^7 \\
   0 & \alpha^{13} & \alpha^9 & \alpha^7 & \alpha^{14} & \alpha & \alpha^6 & \alpha^{12} 
   \end{bmatrix}
   Obviously, summation with first zero vector with any other vector is the vector itself e.g. let us give example of first with second vector, $[ 0, 0, 0 ]^T+ [ \alpha, \alpha^6, \alpha^{13}]^T = [ \alpha, \alpha^6, \alpha^{13}]^T$ and $[C_1, B, A]$ in terms of types. If we look rule 1. and 5. completely satisfies the property and this holds true with all additions of zero vector with any other vectors in the matrix. Another example add second with fifth vector, $[ \alpha, \alpha^6, \alpha^{13} ]^T+ [ 0, \alpha^6, \alpha^{14}]^T = [ \alpha, 0, \alpha^{2}]^T$ and $[C_1, C'_1, C'_2]$ in terms of types. The resulting vector satisfy the property via the rule 1. and 2. . So this vectors will satisfy the property for ALL the sub-set additions of the vectors.

The question is how to create those vectors in n dimension. Is there a specific structural to construct?

Comment: So the rules constrain the (multi)set of components of vectors in your collection? The partitioning of $GF(16)$ that almost but not quite follows the partitioning into cosets of that additive group sounds complicated and a bit artificial. Also, it begs the question: *where do these rules come from?*

Comment: Yes, that is right, the rules constrain the (multi)set of components of vectors. So the normal subgroup $\{0, \alpha, 1, \alpha^4\}$ with the cosets $\{ \alpha^2, \alpha^5, \alpha^8, \alpha^{10}\}$, $\{ \alpha^{13}, \alpha^6, \alpha^{12}, \alpha^{11}\}$ and  $\{ \alpha^{14}, \alpha^3, \alpha^{7}, \alpha^{9}\}$ under  addition is wrong?

Comment: I have come up with that rules. Just curious we can not use some artificial rules and design our problem using our constraints? And, just to give you a bit equivalent but not quite the same problem is when we talk about the famous Erdos coin weighing problem. Will bring us to $\textit{uniquely decodable}$ (UD) codewards (lot of work done for binary $\{0,1\}$, antipodal $\{\pm 1\}$, and ternary $\{0,\pm 1\}$ starting from work of Lindstrom) so basically here the question is all the sub-set sums must result in $\textbf{distinct}$ vectors to be considered UD.

Comment: In contrast to UD problem the resultant vector instead of having $\textbf{distinct}$ vectors it should follow the above mentioned constrain rules.